# Visual C# Building Release but where are needed dll's?

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, release, building

I know that there are many of such threads, but no one tells me completly what to do. I'm writing C# .Net 4.0 Application in Windows Forms and I need to compile it as Release that should working on other computers with installed Full .Net Framework 4.0 only and it should be portable - without installer. 
On PC's with installed Visual Studio (currently I'm using 2012 Pro) exe runs without problems, but on others without VS it lacks for dll's. The problem is to locate which dll's are needed to copy (app just crashes, without error message and Windows tries to find solution).
Is there somewhere a compile flag or something that could give me a list of used dll's or just copy them to Release folder?

Comment: Of course every NET application needs the NET Framework installed on the target computer. Did you install the NET Framework 4.0?

Comment: As I said it is installed. I can't remember now but Windows said that while running an application it throws IOException, I read that can mean missing libraries. I'm not using third-party libraries - only those included with Visual Studio.

Comment: You're using VS 2012, which by default use .NET Framework 4.5. Have you tried to install this version of .NET Framework?

Comment: If you don't use any external libraries in any of your projects and the corresponding framework is installed then a possibility is a missing config file to be deployed with your exes and dlls

Comment: @Steve where to locate this config file? Is it with exe and manifest files?

Comment: @black_wizard I had this problem 2 projects ago, now when I'm creating the new project I'm switching the framework at version 4.0 to run it on WinXP also.

Comment: In your project is usally present a file called `APP.CONFIG`. This file is copied, by VS on build, in the `BIN\DEBUG` or `BIN\RELEASE` folder. In the copy process, the file is renamed `yourAppName.exe.config` and should be deployed with your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the project proporties I found Publish option which made me a setup of the project. There I found that others PC needs not only SQLCe installed but visualbasic packs, don't know why, but they were needed.
After installing both of those installer everything started to working fine on any other PC.
Thank you all for helping.